# Set cell size equal to picture size

Tags: excel, vba, resize

I'm trying to import a picture to excel cell and I'm facing issues with re-sizing.

Steps:

1. Copy/Paste the picture to the cell
2. Re-size the picture manually
3. And also resize  the cell to fix on the picture.

Is there any other way to do it instead of manually?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you meant with re size the picture manually, but might this be working for you?

```
Sub ResizeCells()

Dim X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double
Dim s As Shape

For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.Type = msoPicture Then
        For X = s.TopLeftCell.Column To s.BottomRightCell.Column
            Y = Y + ActiveSheet.Cells(1, X).ColumnWidth
        Next X
        For X = s.TopLeftCell.Row To s.BottomRightCell.Row
            Z = Z + ActiveSheet.Cells(1, X).RowHeight
        Next X
        s.TopLeftCell.ColumnWidth = Y
        s.TopLeftCell.RowHeight = Z
    End If
Next s

End Sub
```

Note:

- Max RowHeight is `409`
- Max ColumnWidth is `255`

Answer (score 0):

This goes the other way.

We will insert a `Shape` from the Internet.
We will move it to cell **B1**.
We will resize the `Shape` *(both height and width)* to fit in **B1**
First place this link in cell **A1**:

http://www.dogbreedinfo.com/images26/PugPurebredDogFawnBlackMax8YearsOld1.jpg

Then run:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call InstallPicture
    Call PlaceAndSizeShape
End Sub

Sub InstallPicture()
    Dim v As String

    v = Cells(1, 1).Value
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures
        .Insert (v)
    End With
End Sub

Sub PlaceAndSizeShape()
    Dim s As Shape, B1 As Range, w As Double, h As Double

    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

    s.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    s.Top = B1.Top
    s.Left = B1.Left
    s.Height = B1.Height
    s.Width = B1.Width
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but nobody mentioned resizing the picture to match the cell.

Excel is very unreliable when I tired to scale the width using @Andrew's code. Luckily, `rCell.Left` is in the correct units. You can get the actual column width using:

```
rCell.Offset(0, 1).Left - rCell.Left
```

Answer (score -1):

This Code will Resize the Cell to Your Picture

```
Sub ResizePictureCells()
For Each Picture In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
PictureTop = Picture.Top
PictureLeft = Picture.Left
PictureHeight = Picture.Height
PictureWidth = Picture.Width
For N = 2 To 256
If Columns(N).Left > PictureLeft Then
PictureColumn = N - 1
Exit For
End If
Next N
For N = 2 To 65536
If Rows(N).Top > PictureTop Then
PictureRow = N - 1
Exit For
End If
Next N
Rows(PictureRow).RowHeight = PictureHeight
Columns(PictureColumn).ColumnWidth = PictureWidth * (54.29 / 288)
Picture.Top = Cells(PictureRow, PictureColumn).Top
Picture.Left = Cells(PictureRow, PictureColumn).Left
Next Picture
End Sub
```